# How to import Blender 3D animation to iPhone OpenGL ES?

Tags: animation, opengl-es, 3d, blender

I am trying to do animations on iPhone using OpenGL ES. I am able to do the animation in Blender 3D software. I can export as a .obj file from Blender to OpenGL and it works on iPhone.

But I am not able to export my animation work from Blender 3D to OpenGL. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at [this article by Jeff LaMarche](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html), you'll find a blender script that will output a 3D model to a C header file. There's also a  [followup article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/improved-blender-export.html) that improves upon the aforementioned script.

After you've run the script, it's as simple as including the header in your source, and passing the array of vertices through your drawing function. Ideally you'd want a method of loading arbitrary model files at runtime, but for prototyping this method is the simplest to implement.

Seeing as you already have a method of importing models (obj) then the above may not apply. However, the advantage of using a blender script is that you can then modify the script to suit your own needs, perhaps also exporting bone information or model keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, I wouldn't recommend .obj for this purpose since the obj file format doesn't support animation, only static 3D models. So you'll need to export the animation data as a separate file that you load at the same time as the obj.

Which file format I would recommend depends on what exactly your animations are. I don't remember off the top of my head what file formats Blender supports, but as I recall it does *not* export Collada files with animation, which would be the most general recommendation. Other options would be md2 for character animations, or 3ds for simple "rigid objects moving around" animations. I think Blender's FBX exporter will work, although that file format may be too complicated for your needs.

---

That said, and assuming you only need simple rigid object movements, you could use .obj for the 3D model shapes and then write a simple Python script to export a file from Blender that has at the keyframes listed, with the frame, position, and rotation for each keyframe. Then load that data in your code and play back those keyframes on the 3D model.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and since then some new iOS frameworks have been released such as GLKit. I recommend relying on them as much as possible when you can, since they take care of many inherent conversions like this, though I haven't researched the specifics. Also, while not on iOS, the new Scene Graph technology for OS X (which will likely arrive on iOS) in the future, take all this quite a bit further and a crafty individual could do some conversions with that tool and then take the output to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [SIO2](http://sio2interactive.com/SIO2_Free_Open_Source_3D_Game_Engine_for_iPad,_iPhone_and_iPod_Touch/SIO2_Free_Open_Source_3D_Game_Engine_for_iPad,_iPhone_and_iPod_Touch.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used recent versions of Blender, but my understanding is that it supports exporting mesh animation as a sequence of .obj files. If you can already display a single .obj in your app, then displaying several of them one after another will achieve what you want.

Now, note that this is not the most efficient form to export this type of animation, since each .obj file will have a lot of duplicated info. If your mesh stays fixed over time (i.e. only the vertices move with the polygon structure, uv coords, etc. all fixed) then you can just import the entire first .obj and from the rest just read the vertex array.

If you wanted to optimize this even more, you could compress the vertex arrays so that you only store the differences from the previous frame of the animation.

**Edit**: I see that Blender 2.59 has export to [COLLADA](http://www.khronos.org/collada/). According to the [Blender manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.5/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA), you can export object transformations, and you can also export baked animation for rigged objects. The benefit for you in supporting the COLLADA format in your iPhone app is that you are free to switch between animation tools, since most of them export this format.