# Developing a talking app on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, opengl-es

I want to develop a talking app for the iPhone and iPad. My question is regarding Animations only. I have an excellent 3D graphics designer who will do his part. Being a programmer, what would I need to be aware of?  What should I ask the designer to provide and in what formats?
Which one to use Core Animation / Cocos 2d for development of 3d character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best process to show an OpenGL Animation in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668245/best-process-to-show-an-opengl-animation-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you look into OpenGL-ES if you are going to do 3D animation on iPhone/iPad.

Here is [the Programming Guide for OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793) on iOS devices.

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I ask the designer to provide?Suppose if I am making a talking tomcat application.What will be the formats and sizes of images for iPhone/iPad?